# JavaFX connected comboboxes

Tags: javafx, combobox, listeners

I could really use some help.

I am  creating application that has two connected comboboxes in a way that if i select productCode in first in second one should be selected productName.

Both combobox textfields are filtrable for search purposes.

I have set setCellFactories like this (for purpose of dropdown list rendering).

```
    cbSifra.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> new ListCell<Product>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Product product, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(product, empty);

            if (product == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(product.getProductCode());
            }
        }
    });

cbNaziv.setCellFactory((comboBox) -> new ListCell<Product>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(Product product, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(product, empty);

            if (product == null || empty) {
                setText(null);
            } else {
                setText(product.getProductName());
            }
        }
    });
```

Both comboboxes implement converters to show data into combobox when selected.

```
cbNaziv.setConverter(new StringConverter<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Product product) {
            if (product == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return product.productNameProperty().get();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Product fromString(String productString)
        {
            return cbNaziv.getItems().stream().filter(item->productString.equals(item.getProductName())).findFirst().orElse(null);

        }
    });


    cbSifra.setConverter(new StringConverter<Product>() {
        @Override
        public String toString(Product product) {
            if (product == null) {
                return null;
            } else {
                return product.productCodeProperty().get();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public Product fromString(String productString)
        {
            return cbSifra.getItems().stream().filter(item ->productString.equals(item.getProductCode())).findAny().orElse(null);
        }
    });
```

Filtering of dropdown list is done using Listener on textProperty() like this:

```
cbNaziv.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {


                cbNaziv.show();

                final TextField editor = cbNaziv.getEditor();
                final Product selected = cbNaziv.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        /*
        This needs run on the GUI thread to avoid the error described
        here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700.
        */

                Platform.runLater(() -> {

            /*
            If the no item in the list is selected or the selected item
            isn't equal to the current input, we refilter the list.
            */
                    if (selected == null || !selected.equals(editor.getText())) {
                        filteredProductList.setPredicate(item -> {
                            // We return true for any items that contains the
                            // same letters as the input. We use toUpperCase to
                            // avoid case sensitivity.

                            if (item.getProductName().toUpperCase().contains(newValue.toUpperCase())) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    }
                });
            });



            cbSifra.getEditor().textProperty().addListener((obs, oldValue, newValue) -> {


                cbSifra.show(); // Is used to open dropdown list as i start typing

                final TextField editor = cbSifra.getEditor();
                final Product selected = cbSifra.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem();

        /*
        This needs run on the GUI thread to avoid the error described
        here: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8081700.
        */

                Platform.runLater(() -> {

            /*
            If the no item in the list is selected or the selected item
            isn't equal to the current input, we refilter the list.
            */

                    if (selected == null || !selected.equals(editor.getText())) {

                        filteredProductList.setPredicate(item -> {
                            // We return true for any items that contains the
                            // same letters as the input. We use toUpperCase to
                            // avoid case sensitivity.

                            if (item.getProductCode().toUpperCase().contains(newValue.toUpperCase())) {
                                return true;
                            } else {
                                return false;
                            }

                        });
                    }
                });
            });
```

I have valueProperty Listeners to check if value is selected and to fill some textFields to their values or set them to null.

```
cbSifra.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Product> observable, Product oldValue, Product newValue) {

                if (cbSifra.getValue() == null || cbSifra.getValue().getProductName().isEmpty())
                {
                    cbNaziv.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    tfMpCijena.setText(null);
                    tfPopust.setText(null);

                } else {


                    cbNaziv.setValue(cbSifra.getValue());
                    cbSifra.setValue(cbNaziv.getValue());
                    cbNaziv.hide();
                    tfMpCijena.setText(cbSifra.getValue().getProductRetailPrice().toString());
                    tfPopust.setText("0");
                }

            }
        });



        cbNaziv.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Product>() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Product> observable, Product oldValue, Product newValue) {

                if (cbNaziv.getValue() == null || cbNaziv.getValue().getProductName().isEmpty())
                {
                    cbSifra.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
                    tfMpCijena.setText(null);
                    tfPopust.setText(null);

                } else {

                    cbSifra.setValue(cbNaziv.getValue());
                    cbSifra.hide();
                    tfMpCijena.setText(cbNaziv.getValue().getProductRetailPrice().toString());
                    tfPopust.setText("0");
                }

            }
        });
```

The problems are :

- when i start typing something into any combobox it filters ok and
  when i   select item from dropdown list it fills second combobox but
  first combobox      editor gets focus again and displays dropdown
  again
- when i delete entry from combobox it deletes ok but the other
  combobox value remains (it isnt deleted)

If you can help me i would really appreciate it.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that both ComboBoxes are of type Product, you can use bidirectional binding to ensure that the values for both ComboBoxes always point to the same product.

```
cbNaziv.valueProperty().bindBidirectional(cbSifra.valueProperty());
```

Using this should allow you to remove your change listeners and will hopefully fix some of the issues you were having.